# Java: Convert windows path to Unix path

Tags: java

I have a path in windows as:

```
C:\\Users\\Sneha\\.netbeans\\5.5.1\\tomcat55.properties
```

How can we convert the above path to Linux path. what does .netbeans and tomcat55.properties path means.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a path pointing to a file named tomcat55.properties. But what do you mean by "converting"?

Comment: probably duplicates with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984907/convert-windows-style-path-into-unix-path-in-java-code

Comment: Converting the path alone will not help you unless you have the same directory structure on the Linux machine. If you just want to convert it will be: /home/Sneha/.netbeans/5.5.1/tomcat55.properties. Because there is no concept of a drive on Linux every path starts with /.

Comment: Yeah right....conversion just would mean \ to /... I actually wanted to know what .netbeans and tomcat55.properties mean......If tomcat55.properties refer to a file, I am unable to find properties file....Is "properties" something we do on right click and properties....

Answer (score 1):

you should read [this webpage](http://www.howtogeek.com/137096/6-ways-the-linux-file-system-is-different-from-the-windows-file-system/) to understand difference between file system in linux and windows.

to convert that windows path to linux path, you must know that names of directories and files are case sensitive in linux,

then except using `C:\\Users\\Sneha` use this method in java to get current user path in any machine(windows, linux and etc.)

```
String user_dir = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

then in linux, path contains only forward slash `/`. not backward slash `\`.

so the path you said

> C:\Users\Sneha\.netbeans\5.5.1\tomcat55.properties

will be

```
/home/Sneha/.netbeans/5.5.1/tomcat55.properties
```

also

- `.netbeans` is a folder,
- `tomcat55.properties` is a file.